# Android app doesn't launch from Eclipse to cell phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm actually trying to run the application I made with my cell phone to test it (my phone is a Samsung Galaxy Core Plus with Android 4.2.2) but my app doesn't start.

When I run my app, and after having chosen the device for running the app, I see this message *"Application has been stopped"* on my phone. I also see many messages on logcat terminal, but I can't understand them and they are thousands so I can't know what's wrong with my app.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks for your answers

Logcat:

```
11-12 16:33:55.007: D/AndroidRuntime(4592): Shutting down VM
11-12 16:33:55.007: W/dalvikvm(4592): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41460930)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.henryhockliffe.androidgame/com.henryhockliffe.androidgame.SampleGame}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.henryhockliffe.androidgame.SampleGame" on path: /data/app/com.henryhockliffe.androidgame-2.apk
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.henryhockliffe.androidgame.SampleGame" on path: /data/app/com.henryhockliffe.androidgame-2.apk
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
11-12 16:33:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(4592):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: it means there is some error in your application. post ur logcat here

Comment: How can I post my logcat?

Comment: just copy what u see in your logcat, then edit ur question and post it. (add 4 spaces bedore 1st line)

Comment: u have not added your ativity i ur manifest file. see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like u have not added your class in your manifest file.

To do so follow these stepes

1) Find manifest.xml file in your project (from the left panel)

2) In your manifest file, add following code inside application tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.henryhockliffe.androidgame.SampleGame" />
```

3) Rebuild your project and run your app

Comment: glad i could help. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue follow the below steps.

**Step 1** - Try to clean your project and disconnect the device from the machine. Plug the machine again.

**Step 2** - In command prompt, navigate to your SDK folder and type adb devices.

You should see your device name and "device" in the column next to it.

**Step 3** - In eclipse run configurations, select "Always prompt to select device" and click Apply.

**Step 4** - Now Run your application and choose your device.

If it pass till step 4 and still you face the issue, copy the logcat logs and paste it in your question. Let me see how i can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Post your LogCat

Steps to do so:

1)Click the very first error

2)scroll to the bottom of the errors, hold shift and click the very last error

```
At this point every error should be highlighted
```

3)press ctrl+C (copy)

4)return here, edit your post, press ctrl+V (paste)

5)highlight everything you just pasted and press the Code Sample button

6)Save edits